# Reading huge amount of Image data with Python and converting them into Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I just have started with Python and Numpy arrays. I am reading a huge amount of image data set located in many different folders. Although, everything is working fine when reading the images, but I continuously getting an error which I am not sure about what really is it. I tried to research for it, but unfortunately I failed to get the real answer. Please help me regarding this issue.

My code is below.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as mpplot
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

images = []
path = "../compCarsThesisData/"

for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
    current_directory_path = os.path.abspath(root)

for f in files:
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        if ext == ".jpg":
           current_image_path = os.path.join(current_directory_path, f)
           current_image = mpimg.imread(current_image_path)
           images.append(current_image)
           print(files)

for img in images:
    print (img.shape)
```

The error I'm facing is below also.

```
 File "reading.py", line 15, in <module>
current_image = mpimg.imread(current_image_path)
File "C:\Users\zeele\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1359, in imread with Image.open(fname) as image:
File "C:\Users\zeele\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2618, in open
prefix = fp.read(16)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

P.S. As a new member please don't mind if the question is unclear or not direct. Your help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Currently the code is not correctly indented and will throw a `SyntaxError`

Comment: @enumaris I edited the code.

Comment: I noticed that your `for f in files:` loop is not part of the `for root,_,files in os.walk(path)` loop. Because of this, `files` will only contain the last `files` object returned in the `os.walk(path)` generator.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works now, but only on the folder which doesn't have multiple folders in it.
For example
I have folder name as "CarDataSet" which contains 2 folders "sv_data" and "data".
"sv_data" is folder which have a lot of .jpg file which it reads perfectly, but I have another folder in the same directory as "sv_data" name "data" which have a lot of multiple folders in it and in this folders I have more folders which contains different images in .jpg format and this code is not working on this now. It just reads the sv_data folder